# Embedded fonts not showing up correctly in PDF generated using pdfpages in pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdfpages, embedding

I am using the `pdfpages` package to include some other PDF documents into a LaTeX document I'm processing with pdfLaTeX.

One of the included PDFs has some uncommon fonts.  They are embedded in the original PDF, and show up fine when looking at the document in Acrobat (Reader or full).  However in the final processed document, certain glyphs do not show up in Acrobat.  pdffonts shows that all of the fonts used in the original PDF are also embedded in the final PDF from the processed LaTeX. The problem is occurring with both TeX Live 2007 on a Fedora 16 box and MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Try in the document with pdfpages `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`. If it doesn't help you will have to make a minimal example and give access to the included pdf.

Comment: That seems to do the trick in one installation.  Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How about a short answer?

Answer (score 7):

Try in the document with pdfpages `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`. If it doesn't help you will have to make a minimal example and give access to the included pdf.