# pdfpages breaks display of small caps

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I try to create proceedings with a uniform title page for individual pdfs that I get from the authors. I use `pdfpages` for this. The individual pdfs are included and I add title information (not shown in the example below). I have one paper that looks fine, but when I include it, the result does not contain the small caps letters in the attribute value matrices (see figures on page 7 and 8).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \setcounter{page}{335}
        \begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Includes/yatabe.pdf}
        \end{document}
```

This is the paper: [yatabe.pdf](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/yatabe.pdf)

What I get from including is [yatabe-broken.pdf](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/yatabe-broken.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Embedded fonts not showing up correctly in PDF generated using pdfpages in PDFLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98353/5764)

Comment: @Werner It is an exact duplicate, save that the answer is not accepted. You have to read the comments to realise that the answer is working.

Comment: @Sveinung: Yes, sorry for not finding the original question, but at the time of asking I did not know about embedded fonts. It was completely mysterious to me. Anyway, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use in the preamble:

```
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1
```

otherwise the SmallCaps font is not included. From the `pdftex` manual:

> `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts (integer)`
>
> If positive, this parameter forces pdfTEX to include fonts from a pdf
>   file loaded with `\pdfximage`, even if those fonts are available on
>   disk. Bigger files might be created, but included pdf files are sure
>   to be embedded with the adequate fonts; indeed, the fonts on disk
>   might be different from the embedded ones, and glyphs might be
>   missing.

Comment: More details can be found at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=pdf-fig-chars.